# Rails JBuilder Partial Missing Template Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

I am creating a mountable rails engine for a wrapper around a 3rd party API.

#### controllers:

`app/controllers/myengine/v1/application_controller.rb 
app/controllers/myengine/v1/customers_controller.rb`

```
module Myengine
  class V1::CustomersController < V1::ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
    def create 
       ... 
    end 
  end 
end
```

#### models:

`app/models/myengine/customer.rb`

#### views:

`app/views/myengine/v1/customers/_customer.json.jbuilder
app/views/myengine/v1/customers/create.json.jbuilder`

I am using JBuilder for my views. Whenever I hit my create action via a REST client, rails will figure out the appropriate view for it (ie. `app/views/myengine/v1/customers/create.json.jbuilder`).

However, when I reference the partial inside `create.json.jbuilder`, it complains that the template is missing.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /v1/customers

Missing partial myengine/customers/_customer with {:locale=>[:en], 
:formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:jbuilder]}. Searched in:

engines/myengine/app/views/myengine/v1/customers/create.json.jbuilder, line 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------

ruby
>   1   json.partial! @customer
```

As you can see its looking for the partial in `myengine/customers/_customer` when it should be looking in `myengine/v1/customers/_customer`.

I could add `json.partial! 'myengine/v1/customers/customer', customer: @customer` to specify where the partial is located and this works. However, typically rails magically knows where to find the partial, just not here for some odd reason.

Your help is much appreciated!!